# Calling @HttpContext.Session["XX"] in .NET Core cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to convert .NET MVC project to .NET Core. But for this I'm getting error like below.

[image]

Earlier it was given as `<h6 class="chart-heading-cls">@HttpContext.Current.Session["XX"] Score Over Time</h6>`. From which I removed the `Current` keyword as it does not exist in the `HttpContext`.

Can you please help on this?

Comment: May be it will work in .NET core if you want to get session value please try and check @HttpContext.Session.GetString("XX");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below sysntex for getting session value in Razor page

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{    
    string sessionvalue = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Sessionkey");    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bad practice! Do not use inject

Comment: article which you refer is for .NET 6 , In .NET 6 we don't need to use the inject method. but in core 3.1 or core 5 you can't use httpcontext wihtout inject.

Answer (score 0):

In aspnet core you must get session with GetString method.

[How sessions work in asp dotnet.core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#session-state)

So the correct usage must be:

```
@HttpContext.Session.GetString("XX")
```

But you can use better, checking if session is null or not:

```
@(HttpContext.Session.GetString("XX")?? "" )
```